# Solr WordDelimiterFilterFactory and words length less than 3

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a text field, the problem is that words like pc, tv get dropped by solr during the search process because their length is less than 3, how can i make solr search for such short search terms ?

```
<analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Thank you !

Comment: Exactly what does the analysis page under the admin interface show for the field?

Comment: Are you using Edge N-Grams  or N-Grams  by any chance anywhere in the schema ? can you post your whole schema.xml

Comment: also can you post your stopwords.txt ?